# Reverse polarity protection for symmetrical input

Tags: circuit-protection, reverse-polarity, over-voltage-protection

I have a symmetrical voltage input I need to protect agains reverse polarity, and over-voltage.

Here is the reverse polarity protection I designed. Is it correct ? I can't find much information about symmetrical voltages circuitry…

[image: reverse polarity protection]

For the over-voltage protection, I'm thinking about that: (with two 16V zener)

[image: over voltage protection]

What do you think about that ? Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply a positive voltage to Vin-, the body diode of Q2 will conduct and you will get the positive voltage minus one diode drop on your -12V signal.

Comment: Okay, I'll just switch the pins 2 and 3 of Q2. That's a lame mistake. https://pics.me.me/thank-you-good-sir-18731694.png